# How to turn on pins 13 and 12 at the same time? Assembly

Tags: assembly, arduino, led, pins

How to turn on pins 13 and 12 at the same time?

```
ldi r18,0x20  ; bit 5 (pin 13) = high
out 5,r18     ; output to port B

ldi r18,0x10  ; bit 4 (pin 12) = high 
out 5,r18     ; output to port B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bitwise OR the values together to set both;

```
ldi r18,0x30  ; 0x20 (bit 5) OR 0x10 (bit 4) = 0x30 sets bit 4 and 5 high
out 5,r18     ; output to port B
```

Comment: thank you very much kind sir :) works perfectly, it's my first day writing assembly. Thank you.